# Include third-party library

Tags: javascript

I have a third party library located in the root/libraries directory, but it is not called on my webpage. I was wondering using subtheme/subtheme.theme or subtheme.libraries.yml. I call it from here? Any information would be great, I can't find documentation on third party libraries for Drupal 8.

Comment: You have to define it in theme.libraries.yml and either attach it with a hook or include it by default in theme.info.yml.

Comment: @Kevin when I add the library to theme.libraries.yml I get an error on my page. The way I call it is as follows, `swiper: (newline, space & 3 line indent) js: /libraries/slick/slick/slick.min.js` . Am I not allowed to call a file outside the scope of the subtheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your library in your file theme.libraries.yml (or module.libraries.yml) like this:

```
# Parsley use for contact_form.
parsley:
  js:
    dist/js/vendors/parsley.min.js: { minified: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

After, you can include your library like any other libraries with a hook or a template.